# How to force text file to download instead of opening in browser in jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp

How to force to text (.txt) file to download instead of opening into browser window.

This is simple html link  `out.print("<a href =http://localhost//output/Output.txt">");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server needs to add a header to the response:

Content-disposition: attachment